# Why is CROSS APPLY resulting in one less row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I split some values (`REPAY_AMOUNT` and `REPAY_REF`) which are delimited special character and cross applied them as follows:

```
SELECT
        ARRANGEMENT_ID,
        REPAY_AMOUNT,
        REPAY_REF,
        CAST(RIGHT(RR.Value,8) AS DATE) 'Split Date',
        RA.Value 'Split Amt'
        
FROM    AA_BILL_DETAILS_Property

        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_REF, N'', '","'), '"]')) RR
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', '","'), '"]')) RA

WHERE   RR.[key] = RA.[key]
ORDER BY    [Split Date] DESC
```

Results are:

| ARRANGEMENT_ID | REPAY_AMOUNT | REPAY_REF | Split Date | Split Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA21084T517V | 3678.412050.25 | AAACT223212XPWZDCY-20221117AAACT222933SXX4KLB-20221020 | 2022-11-17 | 3678.41 |
| AA21084T517V | 3678.412050.25 | AAACT223212XPWZDCY-20221117AAACT222933SXX4KLB-20221020 | 2022-10-20 | 2050.25 |
| AA21084T517V | 1931.41931.4 | AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-SUSPEND-20220228AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-20220228 | 2022-02-28 | 1931.4 |
| AA21084T517V | 1931.41931.4 | AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-SUSPEND-20220228AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-20220228 | 2022-02-28 | 1931.4 |
| AA21084T517V | NULL | NULL | 1900-01-01 |  |
| AA21084T517V | NULL | NULL | 1900-01-01 |  |

**Problem:**

Now I want to split and cross apply another column (`PAY_PROPERTY`) like:

```
SELECT
        ARRANGEMENT_ID,
        REPAY_AMOUNT,
        REPAY_REF,
        CAST(RIGHT(RR.Value,8) AS DATE) 'Split Date',
        RA.Value 'Split Amt',
        PAY_PROPERTY,
        PP.Value 'PP'

FROM    AA_BILL_DETAILS_Property

        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_REF, N'', '","'), '"]')) RR
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', '","'), '"]')) RA
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(PAY_PROPERTY, N'', '","'), '"]')) PP

WHERE   RR.[key] = RA.[key] AND RR.[key] = PP.[key]
ORDER BY    [Split Date] DESC
```

But doing so, I lose one row (i-e, one of the rows having `Split Amt = 1931.4`) resulting in:

| ARRANGEMENT_ID | REPAY_AMOUNT | REPAY_REF | Split Date | Split Amt | Pay_Property | PP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA21084T517V | 3678.412050.25 | AAACT223212XPWZDCY-20221117AAACT222933SXX4KLB-20221020 | 2022-11-17 | 3678.41 | ACCOUNTPRINCIPALINT | ACCOUNT |
| AA21084T517V | 3678.412050.25 | AAACT223212XPWZDCY-20221117AAACT222933SXX4KLB-20221020 | 2022-10-20 | 2050.25 | ACCOUNTPRINCIPALINT | PRINCIPALINT |
| AA21084T517V | 1931.41931.4 | AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-SUSPEND-20220228AAACT22059QK5XTXSD-20220228 | 2022-02-28 | 1931.4 | NULL |  |
| AA21084T517V | NULL | NULL | 1900-01-01 |  | NULL |  |
| AA21084T517V | NULL | NULL | 1900-01-01 |  | NULL |  |

Can someone help please?

Comment: Your new cross apply must not return a value for one row. Try outer apply and see which row it is

Comment: @DaleK Tried it.. Not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I mean by outer apply, I still have the problem of a missing row

Comment: What do mean by 'raw values'? I think they are there in the first two rows

Comment: I can't think of any way using an outer apply would remove a row.

Comment: Presumably `Pay_Property` has fewer elements when split than the other columns do. If they return 2 elements and that only returns one you will lose a row due to `RR.[key] = PP.[key]`. Why are you storing the data like this anyway? RepayRef, RepayAmount and pay property should be stored as rows in their own table not stored as delimited strings and split apart and reassembled into rows by ordinal position

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes you are right about the 3 columns. They should not be here. They are here just for a reference to show you. Only the final split values will go in this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an unequal number of split values in each column, so the join condition is failing. You cannot use an `ON` clause with `APPLY`, so instead you can use `OUTER APPLY`, which works similarly to a `LEFT JOIN`, and move the `WHERE` condition into the `APPLY`.

```sql
SELECT
        ARRANGEMENT_ID,
        REPAY_AMOUNT,
        REPAY_REF,
        CAST(RIGHT(RR.Value,8) AS DATE) [Split Date],
        RA.Value [Split Amt],
        PAY_PROPERTY,
        PP.Value PP

FROM    AA_BILL_DETAILS_Property
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_REF, N'', '","'), '"]')) RR
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', '","'), '"]')) RA
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(PAY_PROPERTY, N'', '","'), '"]')) PP
    WHERE RR.[key] = PP.[key]
) PP
WHERE   RR.[key] = RA.[key]
ORDER BY
    [Split Date] DESC
```

If the other columns also have a variable number of splits then you need a full join:

```sql
SELECT
        ARRANGEMENT_ID,
        REPAY_AMOUNT,
        REPAY_REF,
        PAY_PROPERTY,
        v.*
FROM    AA_BILL_DETAILS_Property
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        CAST(RIGHT(RR.Value,8) AS DATE) [Split Date],
        RA.Value [Split Amt],
        PP.Value PP
    FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_REF, N'', '","'), '"]')) RR
    FULL JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', '","'), '"]')) RA
        ON RR.[key] = RA.[key]
    FULL JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(PAY_PROPERTY, N'', '","'), '"]')) PP
        ON ISNULL(RA.[key], RR.[key]) = PP.[key]
) v
ORDER BY
    [Split Date] DESC
```

Note the `ISNULL` in the second join condition.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/50-r85WS)

Comment: Returns incorrect syntax near PP.  `FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(PAY_PROPERTY, N'', '","'), '"]') PP`

Comment: Sorry missing `)`

Comment: My bad. I should have noticed that. Works like a charm now. Thanks mate! :)